# Prove that logical statement $\phi$ build only with $\leftrightarrow$ is tautology iff every atomic statement of $\phi$ appears even number of times

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Prove that logical statement $\phi$ build only with $\leftrightarrow$ is a tautology iff every atomic statement of $\phi$ appears even number of times.

Hints please,
thank you

Comment: Have you tried using structural induction?

Comment: Second the structural induction Hint!